# Unexpected print behaviour Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running through a tutorial for python 3 and I'm getting strange behaviour on printing. for example:

```
print ("\nUnpickling lists.")
pickle_file = open("pickles1.dat", "rb")
variety = pickle.load(pickle_file)
shape = pickle.load(pickle_file)
brand = pickle.load(pickle_file)
print (variety,"\n",shape,"\n",brand)
pickle_file.close()
```

gives me:

```
Unpickling lists.
['sweet', 'hot', 'dill'] 
 ['whole', 'spear', 'chip'] 
 ['Claussen', 'Heinz', 'Vlassic']
```

How do I avoid the extra space at the beginning of the lines of print output for the second and third lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sep = ''`:

```
print (variety,"\n",shape,"\n",brand, sep = '')
```

Default value of `sep` is a single space:

```
>>> print('a','b')
a b
>>> print('a','b', sep ='')
ab
```

help on `print`: `print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

```
Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.          <-----
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

Answer (score 7):

Just specify `'\n'` as separator, that will spare you to add a newline beteween every item:

```
print(variety, shape, brand, sep='\n')
```